# Install OpenJDK 9 on Ubuntu 16 for all users

Tags: java, ubuntu, sdkman

**What I want:**

I want to install openjdk 9 on my ubuntu (server) machine and it should be available for all users.

**What I have done:**

1. Try to install with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk`

Java version:

`openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)`

This version throws exceptions when using tomcat.

2. Using sdkman (http://sdkman.io/)
   Java version:

   `openjdk version "9.0.4"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)`

This version works well but it's only available for one user and the doc doesn't say how to install/configure it system wide for all users.
It's also not working when I start an application as systemd service.

I don't have much experience with linux and just look for the simplest way to install a working Java 9 version. Please help.

**Edit:**

The exception I got when using the jdk in 1. is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteBufferUtils cannot access class jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.ref to unnamed module @14d7c1f2
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.throwIllegalAccessException(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:411) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.throwIllegalAccessException(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(java.base@9-internal/AccessibleObject.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(java.base@9-internal/AccessibleObject.java:347) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteBufferUtils.<clinit>(ByteBufferUtils.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketBufferHandler.expand(SocketBufferHandler.java:155) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:334) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1436) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158) [na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804) [na:na]
```

It seems that tomcat doesn't notice that it is running in Java 9. When I use the sdkman version I don't get that exception. And this exception causes that the SSL handshake is not working anymore.

I'm using the embedded tomcat of spring boot `2.0.1.RELEASE`

Comment: What exceptions are thrown? - I'm terrible at reading minds.

Comment: I updated my question and included the exception I got

Comment: And what version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: I'm using the embedded Tomcat of Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE. I'm pretty sure that Spring is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up installing Oracle JDK 10 and it's working like the sdkman OpenJDK 9 version for my application.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```

Still no clue why the OpenJDK9 I installed via aptitude is not working...

Comment: For documentation, well into 2020. This issue still persists under Ubuntu 16.04. The aptitude version will install the internal version.

Comment: I read somewhere that newer openjdk version will only be added to aptitude of ubuntu 18+. So I ended up to install the openjdk from version 11 manually.